# Firebase signInSuccessWithAuthResult function is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, this

I'm working on signing in with Firebase through Google auth. When a user does this they then have an account profile created and stored on Firebase if they don't already have one. The problem I'm having is when I try to call the function that creates the new user inside of 'signInSuccessWithAuthResult' I get an error stating: "Cannot read property 'registerNewFirebaseUser' of null". I'm new to React and assuming this is just a gap in knowledge here. Thanks

```
callbacks: {
  signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult) {
    var userRef = fire.database().ref("/users")
    var currentUserID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var userQuery = userRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(currentUserID);

    userQuery.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.exists()) {
        window.location.pathname = '/artistList'
      } else {
        this.registerNewFirebaseUser();
      }
    })
    return false;
  }

registerNewFirebaseUser = () => {
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser !== null) {
   const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
   const newUser = {uid: userId, votes_remaining: 5}
   this.userRef.push(newUser, function () {
    window.location.pathname = '/artistList';
  })
 }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've probably got a problem with your context.  *this* is scoped to your function and not to your *callbacks* object.

Comment: @TylerBurki Thanks for the feedback Tyler, any suggestion on what may be the problem with my function? Like I mentioned I'm new to react and might to be missing something simple. Thanks